# Jquery - onClick - slideUp - slideDown animation

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML code:

```
<div class = "box">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button class = "btn">Click Here</button>
```

and I have this CSS code:

```
.box{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:2px solid black;
}
.box h2,p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

and my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $("h2").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

At this time when I click on my button the h2 is going up and towards left and disappear, and when I click the button again the animation is going down, from left to right and disappear. I would like to have the toggle animation but i would like the h2 to slideUp and slideDown from the middle.

Comment: can you clarify can you mean by 'slideDown from the middle'?

Comment: i mean when i click the button to slideUp from h2 middle and when i click it again to slideDown from h2 middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what exactly is the problem? the animation in the snippet goes back and forth and I think that is what you'd want?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        $(".box1 h2").slideToggle();
    });
  $(".btn2").on("click", function(){
        $(".box2 h2").animate({
          height: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.box{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.box h2,p{
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box box1">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph</p>
</div>
<button class = "btn">Click Here</button>
<div class = "box box2">
    <h2>Hello2</h2>
    <p>This is a paragraph2</p>
</div>
<button class = "btn2">Click Here</button>
```

Comment: As u see the animation of slideUp of the h2 is going up and towards left and when the button is clicked again is going from left towards middle. I would like to click the button and just go up and when i click the button again to slideDown. Instead of going to the top left corner and fade out i would like to go up and fade out and when i click it again i would like to come back down and fade in from the middle.

Comment: Check the snippet again mate, is that it?

Comment: yes thats it, my bad Sam sorry. Thank u for ur answer

Comment: no worries man, I edited it a little after I posted, I also added a secondary possibility but that doesn't seem too smooth .. glad you are helped!